# How can I get php_ESL.dll and load it from php in XAMPP to use it with Mod event socket for freeswitch

Tags: php, freeswitch

I have freeswitch running on a Centos 6 remote server and I have XAMPP installed on the local machine ( windows 7 x64 PHP Version 5.3.8 ) for testing. I am trying to use Mod event socket ( http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Event_Socket ) to connect to freeswitch from a php script, using Event Socket Library ( http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Event_Socket_Library ).

My php script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/php

<?php

require_once('ESL.php');

$command = "show channels";
$sock = new ESLconnection('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', '8021', 'fsAdmin');
$res = $sock->api($command);
printf("%s\n", $res->getBody());

?>
```

where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is the freeswitch server's address.

I have two problems:

- in Windows I seem to need a **php_ESL.dll** which I can't find anywhere. The only files I've got are:

  - ESL.php
  - esl_wrap.cpp
  - Makefile
  - php_ESL.h
- I have PHP Version 5.3.8 and in the ESL.php is used the dl() function and I get: **Fatal error: Call to undefined function dl() in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpesl\ESL.php**

  +The dl() function is called in ESL.php:

  ```
      // Try to load our extension if it's not already loaded.
    if (!extension_loaded("ESL")) {
    if (strtolower(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'win') {
      if (!dl('php_ESL.dll')) return;
    } else {
      // PHP_SHLIB_SUFFIX is available as of PHP 4.3.0, for older PHP assume 'so'.
      // It gives 'dylib' on MacOS X which is for libraries, modules are 'so'.
      if (PHP_SHLIB_SUFFIX === 'PHP_SHLIB_SUFFIX' || PHP_SHLIB_SUFFIX === 'dylib') {
        if (!dl('ESL.so')) return;
      } else {
        if (!dl('ESL.'.PHP_SHLIB_SUFFIX)) return;
      }
    }
  }
  ```

Does anybody know how to solve this or encountered the same problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: To answer both problems 1) You will need to build the DLL yourself from the source code - [see here](http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Installation_for_Windows) 2) [`enable_dl`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.enable-dl) is set to off in your php.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

probably the least effort would be to have a Linux webserver somewhere - for example, in a virtual machine on your windows PC

Answer (score 0):

In your issue I think `dl function` disabled in the php.ini file.

phpmotion requires these PHP settings:

```
Thread saftery= disabled
enable_dl = On
safe_mode = off
```